# Show part of body text of a blog post in publishing site

Tags: web-part, publishing-site, content-query-web-part, blog, sub-site

I have a publishing site, under it there is a blog sub-site. I'm showing the posts from the blog site on the publishing site using a `Content Query` web part. But I'm only able to show the the titles of the posts. When I use 'Body' as summary in the `Content Query`, it shows the `HTML` code in the summary part.

How can I display part of the body text as summary? And also the first image from the body text as a thumbnail?